# Множественное наследование c++

Tags: c++, ооп

Вот сейчас прохожу курс по Программированию на языке C++ (продолжение) на степике и никак не могу решать следующей задачи.

Предположим, что при разработке игры вам потребовался юнит "Челмедведосвин" (ManBearPig).
Завершите разработку иерархии классов и реализуйте необходимые конструкторы.
PS: В данном игровом контексте предполагается, что человек — не животное.

Можете подсказать что я не так делаю.

```
/* этот класс уже определён выше
struct Unit  
{
    explicit Unit(size_t id) 
        : id_(id) 
    {}

    size_t id() const { return id_; }

private:
    size_t id_;
};
*/

// базовый класс для животных
struct Animal : virtual Unit
{
    // name хранит название животного
    // "bear" для медведя
    // "pig" для свиньи
    Animal(std::string const & name, size_t id) 
    : Unit(id)  
    // ...

    std::string const& name() const { return name_; }
private:
    std::string name_;
};

// класс для человека
struct Man : virtual Unit
{
    explicit Man(size_t id)
    : Unit(id){}
    // ...
};

// класс для медведя
struct Bear :  Animal
{
    explicit Bear(size_t id)
    : Unit(id), Animal(name(), id){}
    // ...
};

// класс для свиньи
struct Pig : Animal
{
    explicit Pig(size_t id)
    : Unit(id), Animal(name(), id){}
    // ...
};

// класс для челмедведосвина
struct ManBearPig : Man, Bear, Pig
{
    ManBearPig(size_t id)
    : Unit(id), Man(id), Bear(id), Pig(id){}
    // ...
};
```

Comment: проблем тут две: 1) использование виртуального наследования 2) использование иерархии классов

Answer (score 1):

1. В конструкторе класса Animal вы не инициализируете поле name_

   Должно быть как-то так:

   ```
   Animal(std::string const & name, size_t id) 
   : Unit(id), name_(name) {}
   ```
2. В конструкторах конкретного животного вы имя не передаете.

   Должно быть как-то так:

   ```
   explicit Bear(size_t id)
   : Unit(id), Animal("bear", id){}
   ```